# Nested routing in home/index in sveltekit

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

I am trying to do nested routing as shown in the documentation: https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#layouts-nested-layouts. However, I want the nested routing to happen at home / path. In the example I can nested settings page, however trying to figure out same pattern for homepage as it usually requires creating folder and placing files inside of said folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't**.
There is no layout to **nest** into.

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, things you might want to look into are:

- Using a non-nested layout ( placing a `__layout.svelte` file inside the `src/routes/`) folder.
- Creating a standalone Layout component that you'll import into the toplevel routes and wrap around the content.
- Redirect from the homepage [load function](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#loading) to a subfolder. `home/` or `page/` for example.
- Using the `$page.url.pathname` from [$app/stores](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-stores) inside  `src/routes/__layout.svelte` to detect the top level and render a different layout.